# Are movies shot in parallel when there are scenes with a disjoined set of actors?

Tags: film-techniques

Assuming there are two scenes which have completely different actors, will they be shot in parallel or does it always work in sequence? I assume that the director has to be present at all shots, but then again there are movies with multiple directors.

Comment: not just directors: cameras, sets, crew (light, sound etc) catering, ... lot of things to double up - and why?

Comment: @KateGregory faster shoots?

Comment: The order the scenes are shot is not the order they are shown in the movie - to minimize actor commitment to the shoot, use of sets etc.  Some parallel work can be done by a 'second unit' with a different director but they typically shoot establishing shots, not major scenes with actors in them.

Comment: @iandotkelly That's almost always the case, though there are the rare films that are shot in chronological order. When that happens, there are often news articles about that and how unusual it is.

Comment: Game of thrones is always shot with 2 crews, however it will depend on movie to movie